# PayPal Smart Button: Get Transaction Details & Update into Database

Tags: paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

Hi I am currently doing project that is creating a payment gateway for my webpage and currently I am using PayPal Smart Button for the payment gateway

For now, I have successfully doing the payment but I am unable to get the data that I decided to use for updating the database.  I used the PayPal developer website as reference(code, methods etc.), but it doesn't work. [Get Transaction](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/server-integration/get-transaction/) <-- I am not sure where should I put the provided code in a Controller/Model

I am using ASP.NET MVC for my project.

Please help me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Create two routes that return JSON, one for "Create an order" and one for "Capture an order", documented here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/server-side-api-calls/#server-side-api-calls

Pair your two routes with Smart Button JS for approval. Here is a demo: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

This way when an order is captured, you'll have an immediate API response on your server with all the transaction details. Update your database then.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you mean on the routes that return JSON , Does that mean I have to create class (Model/Controller) for "Create" and "Capture" ?

Comment: You have to create a route on your webserver that when called, performs an API operation, and then responds with only JSON.